# Split path by "\\" in C#

Tags: c#, split

How can I split a path by `"\\"`? It gives me a syntax error if I use

```cs
path.split("\\");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `path.Split('\\')` --- so single quote (for character)

To use a string this works:

```
path.Split(new[] {"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

To use a string you have to specify an array of strings.  I never did get why :)

Answer (score 36):

You should be using

```
path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

if you're trying to split a file path based on the native path separator.

Comment: Well, that depends. It may be appropriate - it may not be. It's only going to be different if running on Mono on non-Windows, of course... at which point you'd still need to know whether the input was *actually* a path for the host OS, or whether it was (say) a filename coming from an HTTP upload.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of handy methods like Path.GetFileName(), Path.GetFileNameWithExtensions() etc

Comment: @Jon: That's not entirely correct... Consider that different language versions of Windows use different characters as the path separator. For example, on Korean versions of Windows, [the Won sign is used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2004/12/14/284838.aspx), and on Japanese versions, [the Yen sign is used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2004/12/14/307152.aspx). So ignoring the fact that those happen to be the same Unicode character, you probably should never hardcode a backslash as the path separator, even if you're *only* going to target Windows.

Comment: @Cody: How does that tally with the docs for DirectorySeparatorChar? "The value of this field is a slash ("/") on UNIX, and a backslash ("\") on the Windows and Macintosh operating systems." (It looks like that's correct, too.)

Comment: @Jon: Honestly, I'm not sure. It might rely on the fact that their code page values are equivalent, so the backslash (reverse solidus) is just displayed as either a Won or a Yen in the relevant version of Windows. And you could do the same thing with your software, I suppose. But I'm generally a fan of not hard-coding information when there's a potentially better solution. It might also be an error in the documentation. That wouldn't be the first time we've seen that. I haven't actually examined on-English versions of the .NET source.

Comment: @Cody Gray, for both Korean and Japanese the path separator is a `\\`, it is just the visual representation that changes. When the default system locale is set to Japanese or Korean the system will show the Yen or Won symbol for the U+005C code point. Horrible, but true.

Answer (score 7):

There's no [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) overload which takes a string. (Also, C# is case-sensitive, so you need `Split` rather than `split`). However, you can use:

```
string bits = path.Split('\\');
```

which will use the overload taking a `params char[]` parameter. It's equivalent to:

```
string bits = path.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
```

That's assuming you definitely want to split by backslashes. You *may* want to split by the directory separator for the operating system you're running on, in which case [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) would probably be the right approach... it will be `/` on Unix and `\` on Windows. On the other hand, that wouldn't help you if you were trying to parse a Windows file system path in an ASP.NET page running on Unix. In other words, it depends on your context :)

Another alternative is to use the methods on [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) and [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) to get information about paths in more file-system-sensitive ways.

Answer (score 7):

To be on the safe side, you could use:

```
path.Split(new[] { Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar });
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows, using forward slashes is also accepted, in C# Path functions and on the command line, in Windows 7/XP at least.

e.g.:
Both of these produce the same results for me:

```
dir "C:/Python33/Lib/xml"
dir "C:\Python33\Lib\xml"
(In C:)
dir "Python33/Lib/xml"
dir "Python33\Lib\xml"
```

On windows, neither '/' or '\' are valid chars for filename. On Linux, '\' is ok in filenames, so you should be aware of this if parsing for both.

So if you wanted to support paths in both forms (like I do) you could do:

```
path.Split(new char[] {'/', '\\'});
```

On Linux it would probably be safer to use Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.Split(new char[] { '\\\' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better just use the existing class System.IO.Path, so you don't need to care for any system specifications.

It provides methods to access any part of a file path like GetFileName(string path) etc.

Answer (score -1):

A complete solution could look like this:

```
//
private static readonly char[] pathSeps = new char[] {
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,
    Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar,
    Path.VolumeSeparatorChar,
};
//
///<summary>Split a path according to the file system rules.</summary>
public static string[] SplitPath( string path ) {
    if ( null == path ) return null;
    return path.Split( pathSeps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
}
```

Some of the other proposed solutions in this article use the syntax:
path.Split(new char[] {'/', '\'});

Although this will work, it has various disadvantages:

1. It does not allow your application to adapt to various target platforms. Currently, our applications are basically running on UNIX and Windows OSs (Win, macOS, iOS, linux variations). So there is a fixed set of path characters. But this might change when dotNET were ported to other operating systems. So it is best to use the predefined constants.
2. Performance of the inline syntax is worse. This might not be of interest for a handful of files, but when working with millions of files there are noticeable differences. The managed memory will go up until next GC. When looking at the generated assembly code you will find "call CORINFO_HELP_NEWARR_1_VC" for each of the 'new' statements, even in Release mode. This happens whenever you new-up any array, because arrays are not immutable. My proposed solution prevents this by declaring the array as readonly and static.
3. Reusability of the inline syntax also is worse, because you might want to use the path separators array in other contexts.
4. StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries should be used to account for UNC paths and possible typos within the incoming path. The operating systems do not allow duplicate path separators, but there might be a typo from the user or a duplicate concatenation of path separator characters, for example when concatenating the path and filename.

Comment: SplitPath by itself is not sufficient; before using it you must also check if the path is in UNC format or not.